# Read multi images in a folder python

Tags: python

I am trying to read read multi images on a folder and do some processing. I have a code that extracts facial landmark coordinates. But I can apply this code to only one image. I want the script to work with all images in the folder. I have read some solutions but they didn't work for me. Can you tell me how can I apply a loop for this?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2
import dlib
import os
from glob import glob

mouth_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/mouth.txt","w")  
lefteye_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/lefteye.txt","w")
righteye_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/righteye.txt","w")  
cascPath = ("C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades_cuda/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
all_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/all.txt","w")
#imagePath = ("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/Dataset/Testing/342_spontaneous_smile_4 (2-17-2018 8-37-58 PM)/342_spontaneous_smile_4 357.jpg") 
mypath=os.path.join("c:", os.sep, "Users", "faruk", "Desktop", "Dataset","Testing2")



PREDICTOR_PATH = ("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/Working projects/facial-landmarks/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

JAWLINE_POINTS = list(range(0, 17))  
RIGHT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(17, 22))  
LEFT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(22, 27))  
NOSE_POINTS = list(range(27, 36))  

#RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(36, 42))
RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list([36,39]) 
ALL_POINTS= list([36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57])
##LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(42, 48))
LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list([42, 45])
##MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list(range(48, 61))
MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list([48,51,54,57])

MOUTH_INNER_POINTS = list(range(61, 68))  

 # Create the haar cascade  
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)  

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)  

 # Read the image  
cv2.namedWindow('Landmarks found',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Landmarks found', 800,800)
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  

 # Detect faces in the image  
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(  
   gray,  
   scaleFactor=1.05,  
   minNeighbors=5,  
   minSize=(100, 100),  
   flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE  
 )  

print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  
   cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)  

   # Converting the OpenCV rectangle coordinates to Dlib rectangle  
   dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(int(x), int(y), int(x + w), int(y + h))  

   landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y]  
               for p in predictor(image, dlib_rect).parts()])  


   #landmarks_display = landmarks[LEFT_EYE_POINTS]
   landmarks_display = np.matrix(landmarks[ALL_POINTS])



   for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks_display):  
     pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])

     cv2.circle(image, pos, 2, color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=-1)


np.savetxt(all_matrice,landmarks_display,fmt='%.f',newline=',')
all_matrice.close()  
 # Draw a rectangle around the faces  
cv2.imshow("Landmarks found", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what you tried and why it did not work for you?

Comment: I tried to use glob and make a loop but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get paths of all images in a directory:

```
import os

#  Folder with images
directory = 'c:/users/username/path/'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        image_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # Your code
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

You need to add your code and process each path. 
Hope this helps.

Edit:

I have no way to test it and it certainly needs a cleanup but might just work. Not sure what image extensions you want to include so i only included jpg.

```
import os
import numpy as np  
import cv2
import dlib


# Chage directory path to the path of your image folder
directory = 'c:/users/admin/desktop/' 

mouth_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/mouth.txt","w")  
lefteye_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/lefteye.txt","w")
righteye_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/righteye.txt","w")  
cascPath = ("C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades_cuda/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
all_matrice= open("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/matrices/all.txt","w")

mypath=os.path.join("c:", os.sep, "Users", "faruk", "Desktop", "Dataset","Testing2")

PREDICTOR_PATH = ("C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/Working projects/facial-landmarks/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

JAWLINE_POINTS = list(range(0, 17))  
RIGHT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(17, 22))  
LEFT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(22, 27))  
NOSE_POINTS = list(range(27, 36))  

#RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(36, 42))
RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list([36,39]) 
ALL_POINTS= list([36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57])
##LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(42, 48))
LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list([42, 45])
##MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list(range(48, 61))
MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list([48,51,54,57])

MOUTH_INNER_POINTS = list(range(61, 68))  

# Create the haar cascade  
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)  

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)  

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        imagePath=os.path.join(directory, filename)

        cv2.namedWindow('Landmarks found',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Landmarks found', 800,800)
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)  
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  

        # Detect faces in the image  
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,  
                                            scaleFactor=1.05,  
                                            minNeighbors=5,
                                            minSize=(100, 100),  
                                            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE  
                                            )  

        print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)  

        # Converting the OpenCV rectangle coordinates to Dlib rectangle  
        dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(int(x), int(y), int(x + w), int(y + h))  

        landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(image, dlib_rect).parts()])  


        #landmarks_display = landmarks[LEFT_EYE_POINTS]
        landmarks_display = np.matrix(landmarks[ALL_POINTS])



        for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks_display):  
            pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])

        cv2.circle(image, pos, 2, color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=-1)


        np.savetxt(all_matrice,landmarks_display,fmt='%.f',newline=',')
        all_matrice.close()  
        # Draw a rectangle around the faces  
        cv2.imshow("Landmarks found", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)  
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

P.s You should try and learn basic programming concepts before you try to tackle something like face recognition or image processing.

Comment: It looks nice thank you. But in my code it converts image to gray with gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) . Here instead of word image, what am i supposed to write ? directory or something else ?

Comment: You dont need to change your code. The part of code i posted has nothing to do with your image processing. Your question was how to apply this code to all files in one directory.

Comment: But i had an error that " name image is not defined " . I am really new on programming :)

Comment: But you didn't mention any error in your question. You said the code works for one image but you want it to work for all.

Comment: Yes it works for single image because name image is defined for a single image. But in your suggestion there is no name image.

Comment: because you need to add your code. The loop i posted will provide you with file path for each image so you need to pass this path to your `image = cv2.imread(imagePath) ` but you also need to include the rest of the relevant code within the loop. The code that actually processes your image. This way loop will execute your code everytime it fetches new path.

Comment: Updated my example .. try it again.